# Как перенести переменную из message handler в callback handler?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Работаю в TeleBot на бд SQLite3

Как правильно переместить переменную из message handler в callback handler?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if (message.text == "text"):
        user_id = message.from_user.id #Вот эту переменную мне нужно переместить
        c.execute("SELECT attempts FROM users WHERE user_id = ?",(user_id,))
        results = c.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            attempts = int(row[0])
            if attempts > 1:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text{attempts}")


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'text':
        user_id = message.from_user.id # Вот сюда
        c.execute("SELECT attempts FROM users WHERE user_id = ?",(user_id,))
        results = c.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            attempts = int(row[0])
            if attempts < 1:
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,message_id=call.message.message_id, text="text{attempts}"
```

Вот при таком исполнении выводит ошибку:

```
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: У вас аргумент в ‘callback_inline(call)’ call, вот к нему и обращайтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажись вам просто нужен юзер айди юзера, который нажал на кнопку. Вот так делайте.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'text':
        user_id = call.from_user.id
```

А если вас интересует ВАШЕ (бота) сообщение, в котором находится нажатая кнопка, то можно вот так

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    msg = call.message
```

Но повторю, это сообщение бота. потому `call.message.from_user` будет принадлежать боту, а не юзеру нажавшему кнопку.